# Mongo shuts down abruptly without any log

Tags: mongodb, server

I get this recurring problem, where Mongo shuts down on the server without any log. I get this error message:

> com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while
> waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN,
> servers=[{address=localh ost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
> exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening
> socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]

and then I check mongo, and it has shut down. But there is absolutely nothing in the log about it crashing or anything.
This is the log from mongod.log:

> 2019-08-27T18:08:48.590+0430 I COMMAND  [conn29] command db.news
> command: find { find: "news", filter: { _id:
> "3bb30383-fa65-4899-99e9-938c5f4979c9" }, limit: 1, singleBatch: true
> } planSummary: IDHACK keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 cursorExhausted:1
> numYields:1 nreturned:1 reslen:28344 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: {
> r: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Collection: {
> acquireCount: { r: 2 } } } protocol:op_query 189ms
>
> 2019-08-28T08:45:24.522+0430 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED
>
> ---

As you can see the first line is the latest query and the second is me running it again.

I am in no way an expert or a sysadmin, and this problem in very concerning so I would very much appreciate any help or guidance you could give me.

Comment: Can you check if you're using the compatible java driver to connect to mongodb? Use this link to check - https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-java

Comment: @Anban yes they are. I don't think the problem is there, since it works for a while and then it shuts down abruptly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is not any log about MongoDB crash, it might the OS has killed mongo processes(due to memory limit problems).you can check killed processes via this command:

- dmesg -T| grep -E -i -B100 'killed process'

Comment: yes. turns out that was the problem. It was using too much swap memory. Thank you for your help.